# Checkbox checked not passing an actual value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

My code checks the value of 2x checkboxes to equal true/false depending on a radio field. I see the checkboxes being ticket on the web page.

However, once they are passed over a HTML POST form, they have no values and always equal false.

If I give the checkboxes a value "TRUE" then of course they have only that value.

What am I missing here?

```
    <script>      
      $(function() {
  var MAIN= $("input[type='radio']");
  var marketingPhone = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='marketingPhone']");
  var marketingRobo = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='marketingRobo']");


    MAIN.on('change', function()
        {
        if ($(this).val() == "TRUE")  {
          marketingPhone.prop('checked',true);
          marketingRobo.prop('checked',true);
        } else {
          marketingPhone.prop('checked',false);
          marketingRobo.prop('checked',false); 
        }

    });
});
  </script>
```

The fields are as follows:

```
        <input type="checkbox" name="marketingPhone" value=""/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="marketingRobo" value=""/>
```

Comment: If you put some value in checkbox than you will get it to backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a `value` in the HTML. If a checkbox is checked, that `value` is posted. These values can be anything and are definitely not the same as the true/false that are used for the `prop()`-call (those just mean 'set or clear the check mark').

Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="marketingPhone" value="yes"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="marketingRobo" value="absolutely"/>
```

When both are checked, this is posted:

```
marketingPhone=yes&marketingRobo=absolutely
```

When not all are checked, the corresponding `name=value` are omitted from the posted data.

---

If you really want to post a value (e.g. "true" or "false") for every checkbox *all the time*, then the only way to do so is by adding hidden fields (one for each checkbox) that you control yourself, setting the value of the hidden field to `"true"` or `"false"` using script. You might as well then not set the checkbox `value` to prevent confusion on the receiving end.

Also be aware that form fields always post strings, so either treat them as literal strings or parse them into booleans on the receiving end.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the input. Is it possible to post 'true' or 'false' as checkbox values that correspond to the prop-set values? 

Thing is, if I add value as true to the checkbox level, then only true is posted, no matter how the prop is set.

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes, if not checked, do not get posted at all with the form.

So if you post a form with checkboxes even if they have some value but they are not checked, you can not get checkbox's values in $_POST or $_GET arrays.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your input. However, if I see the chekcboxes DO get checked on the webpage, then what else do I need to do with them to have a value? The script checks them based on radio button, but these do not post a value it seems.

Comment: Sorry but I am confused here, you do not put any value in checkboxes. So even they would be checked, you can not get their value.

Comment: Oh. Apologies. I thought the "checked" is read as the value. How can I pass the value to the checkbox with my method, if it's possible at all?

Comment: You should put values whatever you want to your checkboxes. And they will be posted with the form only if they will be checked. If not then you can not get even the names of the checkboxes in $_POST or $_GET array keys.
So if `marketingPhone` is not checked and you check `echo $_POST['marketingPhone']` it will throw undefined index.

Hope this is clear to you now.

Comment: In short, you give value to `value` attributes to checkboxes and if you check them, you will get them in php code else not.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! This is only jquery/javascript though, no PHP. If I want to get the 'checked' value true and not-checked as false, can I do this with current code?

Comment: yes, you can do like this: `marketingPhone.is(":checked")` If checked, it will give you TRUE, else FALSE.

Comment: Unfortunately that also did not seem to pass any value to the checkbox. I added it right after the "marketingPhone.prop('checked',true);" line